# When does spark-env.sh runs?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am assuming that spark-env.sh runs when I start the spark cluster with

```
sbin/start-all.sh
```

But, somehow, all environment variables I set inside spark-env.sh are not set after

What is wrong?

1. Spark-env.sh does not run when I restart spark cluster
2. Something is wrong with my spark-env.sh, maybe the syntax
3. The env variables are set, I just cannot see it ...

Comment: You could open `start-all.sh` in a text editor

Comment: well, good answer... Why didn't I think of  it?

Comment: How do you check your environments? If in your program you may need pay attention to this - Quoted from the official doc, "Note: When running Spark on YARN in cluster mode, environment variables need to be set using the spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName] property in your conf/spark-defaults.conf file. Environment variables that are set in spark-env.sh will not be reflected in the YARN Application Master process in cluster mode. See the YARN-related Spark Properties for more information."